# How does asynchronous javascript testing with zombie work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, zombie-process

**The problem**
I have created an app that with express js and am trying to test it with zombie. I have written a number of tests to check the content on web page. I have checked the page manually and the content is correctly loading out of our database. However, when I run our tests I get unpredictable results.

**These are our tests. The first test is failing.**

```
before(function(done) {
   models.Listing.create({name: "Studio Flat in London", text: "This is a great flat in zone one."});
   models.Listing.create({name: "The Fish Market", text: "description"});
   done();
});

beforeEach(function(done) {
   browser.visit('/', done);
});

it('each property should have a title', function(done) {
   expect(browser.html("body")).to.include("Studio Flat in London");

});

it('each property should have a title the fish market', function(){
   expect(browser.html("body")).to.include("The Fish Market");
});
```

The first test fails because it cannot find the the text on the page. The second test passes.

**Comments**
The strange part is that tests that look for the exact same type of content pass. Even tests that look for other content that depends on the database. For example I test for a title and a description and we can find the description.

**Area that could be causing the problem.**
Is this a problem with Asynchronous Testing how does that work?
How do I ensure the page is loaded before the tests run?

Thanks